# Altium Nexus: Linking Managed Sheets to PCB Layout Snippets

Tags: altium

Is there anyway to link Managed Sheets to corresponding PCB layout designs in vault?  I know snippets allows for modular layouts and schematics, but according to what I've read in the documentation, this does not persist in vault and there is no clear link between the schematic snippet and corresponding layout snippet.

Ideally, if I place a Managed Sheet in a new design, I also want the option to place a corresponding layout from vault.  It makes sense to me for the managed sheets to have a link to several pcb layout designs as child items in vault.

Do I have the wrong idea here? At the very least, is there a way to have snippets persist in vault?